# How to prevent Gradle from downgrading a dependency?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I want to use groovy-all 2.5.6 but Gradle for some reason downgrades it:

```
gradlew dependencies --configuration compile | grep groovy
|    +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:{strictly 2.5.6} -> 2.4.12
|    +--- com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.3
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.6
```

Why? How do I prevent it from doing that?

Now I end up with both groovy-2.5.6.jar and groovy-all-2.4.12.jar in my dependencies and am afraid is causing problems.

Thank you!!!

#### Update

```
$ gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency groovy-all
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12 (selected by rule)
   variant "runtime" [
      org.gradle.status          = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage           = java-runtime (not requested)
      org.gradle.libraryelements = jar (not requested)
      org.gradle.category        = library (not requested)
   ]

org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:{strictly 2.5.6} -> 2.4.12
\--- project :myapp-common
     \--- compile
```

Comment: This downgrades it to 2.4. Please share the build.gradle so we can help why this is happening (e.g. you might be forcing deps with a plugin etc)

Comment: Also, grep has cut the tree down so you can't see what's pulling in old groovy

Comment: I would like to but unfortunately I am not allowed to share the build files :'(

Comment: "grep has cut the tree" - but it shows that these are the only dependencies having "groovy" in the name. If groovy / groovy-all was there multiple times (and possibly in different versions) then I could track where the older one comes from. But it isn't. So the full tree does not help, there is no trace to where the 2.4 comes from, its only mention is the one above.

Comment: As https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:identifying_reason_dependency_selection explains, `dependencies` does not explain WHY, which is what I am after, while a [build scan](https://scans.gradle.com/) does. As does `gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency groovy-all`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, through binary search I discovered the culprit:

```
apply plugin: org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin
```

Thanks a lot to @cfrick for the idea that a plugin could be the cause!